# Reset map zoom based on added layers in Folium

Tags: folium

I have a folium map object that I am displaying in a notebook and adding layers to it and displaying again.

So I want to update the zoom level of a map each time I add a layer based on the extent of these layers and previously added layers.

I know I can create a `FetureGroup` and do `FitBounds` but I don't want to have a `FeatureGroup`. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tried this and it worked.

```
map.fit_bounds(map.get_bounds(), padding=(30, 30))
```